# Does Schanuel's conjecture imply that $\pi^e$ is transcendental?

Tags: transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

My understanding (and correct me if I'm wrong) is that it is unknown whether $\pi^e$ is algebraic or transcendental. I've also been led to believe that most open questions of this type would be solved by [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture). For instance, the conjecture implies that $e$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent, and in particular, $e+\pi$ and $e\pi$ are transcendental (currently it is unknown whether either is even rational).

Does Schanuel's conjecture also resolve whether $\pi^e$ is transcendental? (Note that the other way, $e^\pi$ - also called [Gelfond's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%27s_constant) - is known to be transcendental by a special case of the [Gelfond–Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem)).

Comment: The big tools I know about in this area are the [Gelfond–Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), the [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), [Baker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem), and - if true - [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Schanuel's conjecture implies that $\pi^e$ is transcendental. First, note that it implies that $e$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent: $1$ and $2\pi i$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, and so $\mathbb{Q}(1, 2\pi i, e, 1)$ has transcendence degree at least $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.  It follows that $\log \pi$ cannot be rational, since that would give an algebraic dependence between $e$ and $\pi$. Therefore $1, 2\pi i, \log \pi$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, and so $\mathbb{Q}(1, 2\pi i, \log \pi, e, 1, \pi)$ has transcendence degree at least $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, which means $e$, $\pi$, and $\log \pi$ must be algebraically independent. This algebraic independence implies that $1, 2\pi i, \log \pi, e \log \pi$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, and thus $\mathbb{Q}(1, 2\pi i, \log \pi, e \log \pi, e, 1, \pi, \pi^e)$ has transcendence degree at least $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Equivalently, $\mathbb{Q}(i, e, \pi, \log \pi, \pi^e)$ has transcendence degree at least $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, which means $e$, $\pi$, $\log \pi$, and $\pi^e$ must be algebraically independent.

Comment: This is very nice!

Comment: Follow-up question: what about $\pi^\pi$?

Comment: You can apply the conjecture to $2\pi i$, $\log \pi$, and $\pi \log \pi$.